# Find the value of $6^{\log_{10}40}\cdot{5^{\log_{10}36}}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the value of $6^{\log_{10}40}\cdot{5^{\log_{10}36}}$.

---

Let $N=6^{\log_{10}40}\cdot{5^{\log_{10}36}}=6^{\frac{\log40}{\log10}}\cdot{5^{\frac{\log36}{\log10}}}$, but then I got stuck.  Please help me.

Comment: What is your $.5$? Is it $1/2$ or $\times 5$? As answers below show, these variants lead to different answers.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy,it is $\times 5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be simplified to 216:
$$
6^{\log_{10}40}5^{\log_{10}36}=6^{1+\log_{10}4}5^{\log_{10}36}\\=6\times10^{\log_{10}6\log_{10}4}10^{\log_{10}5\log_{10}36}\\=6\times10^{\log_{10}6\log_{10}4+2\log_{10}5\log_{10}6}\\=6\times10^{\log_{10}6\left(\log_{10}4+2\log_{10}5\right)}\\=6\times6^{\log_{10}4+2\log_{10}5}\\=6\times6^{\log_{10}100}\\=6\times6^2=216
$$

Answer (score 2):

Writing $.5$ as $1/2$ and dropping the subscript $10$ from $\log_{10}$ (to make the formulas look nicer), then using the general result that $a^{\log b}=b^{\log a}$ to get started, we have

$${6^{\log40}\over2^{\log36}}={6^{\log40}\over36^{\log2}}={6^{\log40}\over6^{2\log2}}=6^{\log40-\log4}=6^{\log10}=6^1=6$$

**Added later**:  The OP has clarified (in comments) that he/she meant to multiply by $5$, not by $.5$.  The answer now becomes

$$6^{\log40}5^{\log36}=6^{\log40}36^{\log5}=6^{\log40}6^{2\log5}=6^{\log40+\log25}=6^{\log1000}=6^3=216$$

as Element118 also found.